# Cannot run a jar file

Tags: executable-jar

I am trying to open a jar file I downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/sensorml-data-processing/) which is supposed to be an application that tests a sensorML code I wrote. I am expecting an application with an interface where I| would put my code and get some kind of output... I am unable to open the jar file. I tried the command window, I get could not find or load main class. I tried opening it with eclipse, I get some kind of library with a lot of errors. There is no documentation about this library or application so I am kind of lost on what to expect and how to get it... Anyone can help me open this file in a correct way?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, you should probably remove the tag and replace it with the tag "Java". Also, you might want to post your programming code and show where you get stuck. If not, then this question doesn't belong here, you should ask on something like superuser.com or another Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

The only jar available near the URL you like isn't an executable jar. It is a library to write programs. To open it you can rename it as .zip and uncompress it.

You can also download the .tar.gz version of this library so you can get the full source with all comments.